# Calculating hours of sunlight in a year based on latitude

Tags: javascript, calculator

I need to calculate amount of hours of sun in a year based on lat and long.

I am creating a solar calculator which will factor in sun hours during a year to output annual variables.

I found this calculation: [Calculate daylight hours Based on gegraphical coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6372802/calculate-daylight-hours-based-on-gegraphical-coordinates)

To clarify, the calculation in the thread above looks good but the date/time bit can be eliminated because I just need annual value.

Any help would be gratefully appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: language, framework, platform?

Comment: Where are you stuck, what have you tried?

Comment: 55.8700° N, 4.2700° W AKA Glasgow - They do not know what the Sun looks like! Ed in Edinburgh

Comment: I'm guessing you want the integral from 1 to 365 dJ of that horrible equation in your link.  Longitude doesn't matter.  Also you are assuming that the ground is flat, because it won't work for people who live next to mountains for example.

Comment: I'll create a JS class that does the calculations now. Will probably take me several hours but sounds like a fun evening project.

Comment: @Layke - You need to get out more. Just doing babysitting myself. The hound, my daughter and boyfriend are all asleep.

Comment: Lol guys, Layke, will happily send you 10$ if you crack it. Need annual values only.

Comment: Okay. I've finished. I'll post the solution tomorrow though. I need to tidy it all up. From what I can tell it works correctly... Hard to kind of test to know if it is correct, but I'll let you do the testing.

Answer (score 0):

While you wait for Layke's class, here is the quick and dirty:

```
function sunshine(L){
    var total=0,P,D,I;
    for(var J=0;J<=365;J++){
        P=Math.asin(.39795*Math.cos(.2163108 + 2*Math.atan(.9671396*Math.tan(.00860*(J-186)))));
        I=(Math.sin(0.8333*Math.PI/180) + Math.sin(L*Math.PI/180)*Math.sin(P))/(Math.cos(L*Math.PI/180)*Math.cos(P))
        D= 24-((24/Math.PI)*Math.acos(I));
        total += D;        
    }
    return total;
}

console.log(sunshine(55));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rrmn8/

Answer (score 0):

Took about 6 hours to get it together. I managed to find a lot of required algorithms from some Java classes. I've created the class as a AMD loadable module, but I figure that you probably don't use AMD so it's loadable without AMD as well.

None of the algorithms used are under copyright and are publicly published in such places as the astronomy almanac.

I created the repository under [GitHub Sundial](https://github.com/Kalyse/Sundial) it is licenced under the permissive modified BSD license, so you can use it freely in your own projects.

It should be accurate to 0.0001 minutes and takes into account the [axial tilt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axial_tilt) of the earth, and the [equation of time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equation_of_time).

### [Sundial](https://github.com/Kalyse/Sundial) AMD Loadable Sun Day Light Calculator

```
/*  Credit and References */
// http://lexikon.astronomie.info/zeitgleichung/   EOT 
// http://articles.adsabs.harvard.edu/cgi-bin/nph-iarticle_query?bibcode=1989MNRAS.238.1529H&db_key=AST&page_ind=2&plate_select=NO&data_type=GIF&type=SCREEN_GIF&classic=YES
// http://code.google.com/p/eesim/source/browse/trunk/EnergySim/src/sim/_environment.py?spec=svn6&r=6
// http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/56478.html 
// http://www.jgiesen.de/elevaz/basics/meeus.htm
// http://www.ehow.com/how_8495097_calculate-sunrise-latitude.html
// http://www.jgiesen.de/javascript/Beispiele/TN_Applet/DayNight125d.java
// http://astro.unl.edu/classaction/animations/coordsmotion/daylighthoursexplorer.html
// http://www.neoprogrammics.com/nutations/Nutation_In_Longitude_And_RA.php
(function (factory) {
    if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ) {
        // AMD. Register as module
        if(typeof dojo === 'object') {
            define(["dojo/_base/declare"], function(declare){
                return declare( "my.calc.Sun", null, factory());
            });
        } else {
            define( 'Sundial', null, factory());
        }
    } else {
        Sun = new factory();
    }
}(function () {   
    return {
        date : new Date(),  
        getDate : function(){
          return this.date;  
        },
        setDate : function(d){
          this.date = d;
          return this;
        },
        getJulianDays: function(){
            this._julianDays = Math.floor(( this.date / 86400000) - ( this.date.getTimezoneOffset() / 1440) + 2440587.5);
            return this._julianDays;
        },
        // Calculate the Equation of Time
        // The equation of time is the difference between apparent solar time and mean solar time. 
        // At any given instant, this difference will be the same for every observer on Earth.
        getEquationOfTime : function (){        
            var K = Math.PI/180.0;
            var T = (this.getJulianDays() - 2451545.0) / 36525.0;   
            var eps = this._getObliquity(T); // Calculate the Obliquity (axial tilt of earth)
            var RA = this._getRightAscension(T);
            var LS = this._getSunsMeanLongitude(T);
            var deltaPsi = this._getDeltaPSI(T);                    
            var E = LS - 0.0057183 - RA + deltaPsi*Math.cos(K*eps);     
            if (E>5) {
                E = E - 360.0;
            }
            E = E*4; // deg. to min     
            E = Math.round(1000*E)/1000;                                
            return E;       
        },
        getTotalDaylightHoursInYear : function(lat){
            // We can just use the current Date Object, and incrementally
            // Add 1 Day 365 times... 
            var totalDaylightHours = 0 ;
            for (var d = new Date(this.date.getFullYear(), 0, 1); d <= new Date(this.date.getFullYear(), 11, 30); d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1)) {
                this.date = d;
                // console.log( this.getDaylightHours(lat) );
                totalDaylightHours += this.getDaylightHours(lat);
            }
            return totalDaylightHours;  
        },
        getDaylightHours : function (lat) {
            var K = Math.PI/180.0;
            var C, Nenner, C2, dlh;
            var T = (this.getJulianDays() - 2451545.0) / 36525.0;   
            this._getRightAscension(T); // Need to get the Suns Declination

            Nenner = Math.cos(K*lat)*Math.cos(K*this._sunDeclination);
            C = -Math.sin(K*this._sunDeclination)*Math.sin(K*lat)/Nenner; 
            C2=C*C;
            // console.log( T, C2, C, Nenner, lat, K,  Math.cos(K*lat) );
            if ((C>-1) && (C<1)) {
                dlh=90.0 - Math.atan(C / Math.sqrt(1 - C2)) / K;
                dlh=2.0*dlh/15.0;
                dlh=Math.round(dlh*100)/100; 
            }
            if (C>1) {
                dlh=0.0;
            }
            if (C<-1) {
                dlh=24.0;
            }
            return dlh;
        },
        _getRightAscension : function(T) {  
            var K = Math.PI/180.0;              
            var L, M, C, lambda, RA, eps, delta, theta;                     
            L = this._getSunsMeanLongitude(T); // Calculate the mean longitude of the Sun       
            M = 357.52910 + 35999.05030*T - 0.0001559*T*T - 0.00000048*T*T*T; // Mean anomoly of the Sun
            M = M % 360;        
            if (M<0) {
                M = M + 360;
            }       
            C = (1.914600 - 0.004817*T - 0.000014*T*T)*Math.sin(K*M);
            C = C + (0.019993 - 0.000101*T)*Math.sin(K*2*M);
            C = C + 0.000290*Math.sin(K*3*M);       
            theta = L + C; // get true longitude of the Sun                     
            eps = this._getObliquity(T);                
            eps = eps + 0.00256*Math.cos(K*(125.04 - 1934.136*T));      
            lambda = theta - 0.00569 - 0.00478*Math.sin(K*(125.04 - 1934.136*T)); // get apparent longitude of the Sun
            RA = Math.atan2(Math.cos(K*eps)*Math.sin(K*lambda), Math.cos(K*lambda));                
            RA = RA/K;
            if (RA<0) {
                RA = RA + 360.0;
            }           
            delta = Math.asin(Math.sin(K*eps)*Math.sin(K*lambda));
            delta = delta/K;        
            this._sunDeclination = delta;               
            return RA;      
        },
        // Calculate the Mean Longitude of the Sun
        _getSunsMeanLongitude : function(T){
            var L = 280.46645 + 36000.76983*T + 0.0003032*T*T;  
            L = L % 360;        
            if (L<0) {
                L = L + 360;
            }
            return L;           
        },
        // Nutation in ecliptical longitude expressed in degrees.
        _getDeltaPSI : function(T){
            var K = Math.PI/180.0;
            var deltaPsi, omega, LS, LM;            
            LS = this._getSunsMeanLongitude(T); 
            LM = 218.3165 + 481267.8813*T;      
            LM = LM % 360;  
            if (LM<0) {
                LM = LM + 360;
            }   
            // Longitude of ascending node of lunar orbit on the ecliptic as measured from the mean equinox of date.
            omega = 125.04452 - 1934.136261*T + 0.0020708*T*T + T*T*T/450000;
            deltaPsi = -17.2*Math.sin(K*omega) - 1.32*Math.sin(K*2*LS) - 0.23*Math.sin(K*2*LM) + 0.21*Math.sin(K*2*omega);
            deltaPsi = deltaPsi/3600.0;     
            return deltaPsi;    
        },
        // T = Time Factor Time factor in Julian centuries reckoned from J2000.0, corresponding to JD
        // Calculate Earths Obliquity Nutation
        _getObliquity : function (T) {
            var K = Math.PI/180.0;
            var LS = this._getSunsMeanLongitude(T);
            var LM = 218.3165 + 481267.8813*T;  
            var eps0 =  23.0 + 26.0/60.0 + 21.448/3600.0 - (46.8150*T + 0.00059*T*T - 0.001813*T*T*T)/3600;
            var omega = 125.04452 - 1934.136261*T + 0.0020708*T*T + T*T*T/450000;       
            var deltaEps = (9.20*Math.cos(K*omega) + 0.57*Math.cos(K*2*LS) + 0.10*Math.cos(K*2*LM) - 0.09*Math.cos(K*2*omega))/3600;
            return eps0 + deltaEps; 
        }
    };
}));
```

### Demo jsFiddle

You can check out a demo of how you might use it on jsfiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/wjKRw/

And then when I get around to it, check out the sample use cases at the repository. 
[GitHub Sundial](https://github.com/Kalyse/Sundial)

Comment: I've realised that while this provides the time that the sun offers light, since you are using it for solar panels, barely any of the early and late sunlight will be of use. The question is probably flawed from the beginning, unless you also plan to use cloud coverage averages per region as well.